# Writing if statement that can accommodate multiple 'or' conditions

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a scenario where I am creating a new variable that will have only the `servces` values from a list of values available in `filex`.

```
$ cat filex

all_name1_db
all_name2_dm
alm_service1_ax
all_name3_du
alz_name4_dx
ali_name5_dk
alk_service2_av
alf_name6_df
alj_name7_dq
```

Here is the code that I use to create a variable `services` which will have only the values that has services in it.

```
for x in $filex
do
 if [[ $x == *"service1"* ]] || [[ $x == *"service2"* ]];then
   Services+=$x","
 fi
done
```

My end result will be a comma delimited value shown below.

```
$ cat $Services

alm_service1_ax,alk_service2_av
```

The problem now is, the `service` value is keep on increasing in `filex` and I can't extend my `if` statement by adding `||`. For instance, if I have a new service say `bum_service3_bk` included in `filex` then my `if` statement would look like this..

```
...
 if [[ $x == *"service1"* ]] || [[ $x == *"service2"* ]] || [[ $x == *"service3"* ]] ;then
...
```

and this will keep on increasing for every new `service` added in `filex`

Is there a way to write an `if` statement to have a single condition that can accommodate multiple or conditions or any better way to tackle my issue?

Comment: What's the problem with adding more `||` parts? Can you not simply do `[[ $x = *service* ]]` here? If you want something shorter, you can use a standard `case` construct instead of those `ksh` `[[...]]`s: `case $x in service1|service2|service3) ...;; esac`

Answer (score 0):

[Avoid loops to process text](/q/169716). Here:

```
grep 'service[123]' filex | paste -sd , -
```

Or:

```
grep 'service1
service2
service3' filex | paste -sd , -
```

Comment: What if I need to write the else part to another variable? In this case, I want to write the `name` values to another varible `Nmaes`. Using `if` statement I can achieve this using `else`. How can we go about that?

Answer (score 0):

If you need one line answer then use :

```
grep "service" filex | xargs echo | sed 's/ /, /g'
```

OR

if you need conditional syntax then you can do like :

```
while read -r line
do
if [[ $line == *"service"* ]]
then
   Services+=("$line")
fi
done < "/tmp/filex"

echo "${Services[@]}" | tr ' ' ,
```

It will gives like:

```
alm_service1_ax,alk_service2_av,alk_service5_av,alk_service3_aff,alk_service5_afds
```

`/tmp/filex` - is path of your file

`echo "${Services[@]}" | tr ' ' ,` - printing comma separated array

Comment: I have provided the service name as generic. The actual service name is different country's name. Like, Japan, US, China. I want to build the service string with the services that has the above country names. The way I use is multiple or conditions in the `if` statement. Is it possible to make a config file and maintain all the country names in it and do a lookup from it?